# how to get a variable from script to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

//how to get a value in php variable instead of input type from script

"href="#mymodal" data-target="#myModal" > $order_id ";?>

//script for getting a value after clicking on a id

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a[rel=dialog]").click(function(){
get this var id on php variable         
   var id =$(this).attr("data-id");
            $('#products_id_textbox').val(id);
            console.log("Order id-"+id);
       });  


    });
</script>
```

//mymodal box displaying a value-
    
      
            
          
            ×

```
//able to get the value in  input type
<input type="text" id="products_id_textbox"></input>
<?php
//get the value here instead of input type in php variable
?>    
        </div>

        <td>Passenger Name </td>
        <td>Mobile No</td>
    </tr>


        <tr>


        </tr>

</table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Comment: Bit confuse from your question but, if u want to get the variable value from PHP to JavaScript... then you've to send that value by AJAX call to PHP.

Comment: i want value from javascript tp php instead of input type i need it in php variable

Comment: let me know any possibilty

Comment: AJAX is the only solution for that.

Comment: have you tried json_encode?

Comment: can we tell me the approach

Comment: Check this Jquery Code - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ . I think u don't know a lot about ajax. If that so, then learn some JavaScript & then Jquery. It's easy.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion